# Does react-active app is ok for AppStore?

Tags: react-native

Does React-Native APP is ok for AppleStore?

I want to know is there any App in AppleStore is written by React-Native?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several apps with React Native in the App Store from various companies.